# How To Check If HTML5 Video Is Playing With Selenium Webdriver In C#?

Tags: c#, html, firefox, video, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to check if a video is playing using Selenium via C# during a firefox session? Would like to write a test where the webpage loads and a check is made to see that the video has started playing automatically.

I was asked this question the other day but didn't know how to answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which player is used on your website. E.g. on youtube main div element (with id 'movie_player') which contains video player has some specific attributes. Then video is paused one value in 'class' attribute changed to 'paused-mode', but if you click on play btn in player then this attribute will be changed to 'playing-mode'. So, one of the possible ways to know whether video is playing or not is to check values of some attributes (as in example with youtube).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use Javascript.
You can see command from here: [HTML Audio/Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)